# Chatbase integration with Dialogflow chatbot which is integrated in an app through a third party API

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbase

I have a Dialogflow agent which is integrated in an app and a web version. I want to integrate this chatbot with Chatbase to get analysis metrics of the bot. However, as of chatbase documentation we cannot integrate Dialogflow hosted bots with Chatbase but if I have a server in the middle of my app and chatbot which is saving all the data, can I integrate chatbase with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to integrate Chatbase is to have it called as part of fulfillment. This requires you to set each Intent to use fulfillment, but you can still set the reply as part of the Intent, if you wish. In your webhook, you would call Chatbase to record the event, but not return any response in the webhook, and Dialogflow will use the Response set in the UI.

Comment: So from your answer what I understand is that if I am calling Chatbase through webhook the only events being recorded there would be when user submits a query for Dialogflow chatbot. Am I right? However, in my current chatbot architecture we have the entire conversation being saved as JSON files on the server. Can Chatbase read those files?

Answer (score 1):

Chatbase reports are built upon user messages and intents, however there is value in sending us the bot messages to provide context to the [Transcripts](https://chatbase.com/documentation/transcripts) feature. You can create a server to server integration to send us the JSON payloads in real time, or in batches of up to 100.